# AWK interval expressions to clean IP

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

*Credit to a great many entries from you online and manuals.*

It works, but, is it efficient enough?
Do you approve?
{Reading logs +- 5k items fast as I can see}

**Source data from file "myAwk3.txt":**

```
type,Srv-1,2016-04-16 ﻿23:59:02,Name1,1234567890abcdef123456789bbbbb00,(10.90.178.4:1004)
type,Srv-1,2016-04-16 ﻿23:59:24,<N@me> (-) [==]1 23,1234567890abcdef123456789bbbbb22,(192.10.196.74:65005)
```

**Code that works now:**

```
awk --re-interval -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=",";}{ 
patPort=":[0-9]{1,5}";              # Will find ":1" to ":65xxx"
IpPort=$6                           # Field needed, (192.10.196.74:65005)
IpOnly=gensub(patPort, "",1,$6);    # Remove pattern
IpOnly=gensub(/[(]/, "",1,IpOnly);  # Remove "(" , With sed: sed 's/[()]//g' 
IpOnly=gensub(/[)]/, "",1,IpOnly);  # Remove ")"
print IpPort, IpOnly;               # Show old and new data
} ' myAwk3.txt
```

**Result:**

```
(10.90.178.4:1004),10.90.178.4
(192.10.196.74:65005),192.10.196.74
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to eliminate the regex match and substitution overhead:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    { 
        split($6, a, ":");
        print substr(a[1], 2);
    }
' myAwk3.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much Guido. Works perfect. You helped me a few days ago with first issue. Hours, days later it all almost works now. No idea how I did not learn this stuff 20 years ago. I am much obliged.